# How to auto left click a specific location of a specific window while im working on another window?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, utilization

Is there any way to (preferably repetetive and rapidly) auto left click a specific location of a specific window with having the comfort to use the other windows at the same time ? I've tried so many auto clickers but none of them has this feature. Currently im using Speed Auto Clicker but i have to stop it when i want to tab to a different window. I need it to continue to clicking on the previous window when i tabbed out to a different window. Any kind help is insanely appreciated.

Comment: This is probably very hard because of the way windows handles focus, but it might be able to find a easy workaround if it is possible to have the "autoclick window" running inside a virtual machine. Would this work for your use case?